# Cortana is still calling a bot I've deleted

Tags: azure, bots, cortana

I was asked to make cortana invoke a local exe (WinForms).
So I created a bot using the SDK to execute the assembly but for technical reasons this didn't work.

Now my problem is, I've already finished the requirement, by building a UWP app instead that calls the EXE and everything is fine.

But now Cortana sometimes calls the bot and sometimes calls the UWP app.
**Even** after I've deleted the bot (2days ago) and terminated the subscription at the time (different reason, costly) it is still able to call the bot.

I've removed my account from windows and cortana, and yet it is able to reach it - or atleast attempting to.

Is there anyway to sever the connection to the bot via cortana?
The bot is no longer available, so I can't remove it from Cortana from its channels.

Comment: I solved this by creating a new skill using the SAME name as the old one and linking then unlinking it from the Cortana channel - Seems to be buggy implementation by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the bot developed as a third party cortana skill?  If so, the way to disconnect Cortana from the skill is to remove the cortana channel (button on the channel registration).  If you simply remove the bot, there may be a delay in the time it takes to tear down the channel.  However, you say it still invokes your bot.  Did you delete all the resources for the bot? When you published the bot, I gather you only published to yourself. Can anyone else see the bot?  If you feel something got stuck, send the bot id and invocation name to skillsup at microsoft dot com and ask them to manually remove the cortana channel.  This would free up the invocation name if locked.

Comment: Sadly I forgot about removing Cortana from the channel and instead removed the bot itself. And yes, I've removed all the resources within the Azure account, just in case.
The bot was only published to myself, but for some reason even when windows is not connected to any online account it still was able to call the bot.
The solution for me was extra - Use a completely different account for Alexa - I used my work outlook account and it worked.
I will send a mail to skillsup and see if they can remove it though. I would like to be able to use my main account on windows without this problem.